# how to get a specific file address in a computer in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to find a video (.mp4)  file which is present in some specific folder which is unknown to me. The file has the attributes Hidden, System and Directory.
I have written the code to find the file with that extension, but still the code is not finding that particular file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> path = new List<string>();
    string fileName = "javascript_part1.mp4";
    foreach(DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x=>x.IsReady))
    {
        foreach(string d1 in Directory.GetDirectories(d.Name))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach(string d2 in Directory.GetDirectories(d1))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        path.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(d2, fileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach(string s in path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Please if anyone can suggest what the problem is in the code or any suggestion for modification of the code to get the desired result.

Comment: Your code is built to go exactly two directory levels deep, and in that second directory level you look for the file in question. This won't work if the file isn't exactly 2 down, but on some other level.

Comment: i had written code to check from the drive level but when exception is coming access to path is denied it is not searching for other folder it handles the exception and change the drive. So suggest code if exception is coming how to search in other folders except of changing the drive.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter B already mentioned, you don't look deep. So you need kinda recursion, like this:

```
public static string FindFile(DirectoryInfo folder, string fileName)
{
    if (folder.EnumerateFiles().Where(x => x.Name == fileName).Any())
    {
        return folder.FullName;
    }

    foreach (var newFolder in folder.EnumerateDirectories())
    {
        return FindFile(newFolder, fileName);
    }

    return "Nothing found";
}
```

Comment: `folder.EnumerateDirectories()` and `folder.EnumerateFiles()` would likely be faster.

Comment: Also `.ToArray().Length > 0` is satisfying a condition that is already hit.  Try this instead: `if (folder.EnumerateFiles().Any(x => x.Name == fileName)) {...}`